# Fennec tab open event

Tags: javascript, mozilla, fennec

How do I listen for a tab open event in fennec? The `gBrowser` object doesn't exist and the closest thing to it I could find was the `Browser` object, but it doesn't let me attach listeners to it.

Answer (score 1):

from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/CodeSnippets
The `Browser` object fires a few Tab-specific events. You can use these events to monitor tab browser lifecycle: TabOpen, TabSelect, and TabClose. Here's an example of hooking up listeners for the events:

```
function startup() {
  let tabs = document.getElementById("tabs");
  tabs.addEventListener("TabOpen", onTabOpen, true);
}

function onTabOpen(event) {
  let newTab = event.originalTarget;
}
```